# Appstore - An application with only Youtube videos will be accepted?

Tags: iphone, app-store

this is my question...

I have a compilation(UITableView) of videos from youtube of a particular genre (funny videos, for example) and I want to know if this app will pass the approval process.

These videos are freely accessible by anyone in youtube, but isn't uploaded/recorded by me.

This is a concept:
http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/3466/img0075.png

(obviously with a cool skin design and more options like Favorites, Share with friends, etc)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be breaching several license terms by doing that, not only Apple's but also YouTube's:

Excerpt from YouTube license terms, paragraph 5:

> Your Use of Content on the Site In addition to the general restrictions
>   above, the following restrictions and
>   conditions apply specifically to your
>   use of content on the YouTube Website.
>
> ...
>
> B: You may access User Submissions for
>   **your information and personal use solely as intended through the
>   provided functionality of the YouTube
>   Website.** You shall not copy or
>   download any User Submission unless
>   you see a “download” or similar link
>   displayed by YouTube on the YouTube
>   Website for that User Submission.
>
> ...
>
> E: You agree to not engage in the use,
>   copying, or distribution of any of the
>   Content other than expressly permitted
>   herein, **including any use, copying, or
>   distribution of User Submissions of
>   third parties** obtained through the
>   Website for any commercial purposes.

There are probably other terms from YouTube that prevents you from distributing these movies though you own application. But just one of those caluses prevents you from distributin it though AppStore as detailed in Apple's terms:

> 5.1   You represent and warrant that: (a) You have the right to enter into
>   this Agreement, to reproduce and
>   distribute each of the Licensed
>   Applications, and to authorize Apple
>   to permit end-users to download and
>   use each of the Licensed Applications
>   through one or more App Stores; (b)
>   **none of the Licensed Applications, or
>   Apple’s or end-users’ permitted uses
>   of those Licensed Applications,
>   violate or infringe any patent,
>   copyright, trademark, trade secret or
>   other intellectual property or
>   contractual rights of any other
>   person, firm, corporation or other
>   entity;** 
>   ...

So the answer in short is no.

Comment: It depends, I think. Does your app need an internet connection to run? If you cache the videos "on demand", then its just like the native youtube app or (maybe) a video embedded into a website. However, if the videos are pre-downloaded (the user can see them without internet), then it's in violation. I'm not a lawyer however, so don't take my word for it!

Comment: I don't see how the above would be a reason not to do this, though there might be others. Linking to a Youtube video is not the same as copying the actual data from it. Linking to Youtube videos are actively endorsed at the Youtube page. Doh?

Answer (score 2):

If everything you can do with this app is possible (easily) with the Youtube app that Apple ships, it will probably not be approved. The app has to add some value. Apple has disapproved apps that copied apps that shipped with iOS before. If your app adds something it will probably be approved.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I see no reason that Apple will reject this app